# hitting knox rest services using java?

Tags: java, httpclient, knox-amazon-s3-client

I am new to apache knox. I have configured knox and started playing with it using command line. So Now I want to hit knox webservices using java httpclient. Is there any example or guide for this?

Or there is only groovy script for this purpose?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use browser REST clients like POSTMAN.Easy to use.

To get it.., Launch your chrome browser goto chrome extension library (google it) then search for POSTMAN REST CLIENT . add it to your chrome extensions.